# List of ROS-enabled robots

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I know there is a list here http://robots.ros.org/. But it seems somehow short (for instance, I remember there was Parrot drone supported few years ago and it is not on the list) . Is this final list of ROS supported robots? I am particulary looking for robotic arms.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259861/list-of-ros-enabled-robots/) by [Tomaszz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19879/tomaszz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer; That page isn't final list.

The long one; If you have created one robot which works with ROS, You can simply add new page on [wiki.ros.org](http://wiki.ros.org) and add your new robot. I'm visiting that page's old version for years and it doesn't shows all the robots.

If you want to contribute; Search the robots which works with ROS and doesn't listed on that page, and add a new page, add new one(s). And clone and edit github page: [ros-infrastructure/robots.ros.org](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/robots.ros.org), and request merge.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0